# How to use one callback from singleton in multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

how to use `onCompleted` in multiple classes views.

**UPDATED FULL CODE !!!**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class AudioSyncManager {

    //var onDownloadStart: (()->())?
    var onDownloadFinished: ((_ isSuccess: Bool)->())?
    var onDownloadProgress: ((_ progress: Float)->())?

    static let shared = AudioSyncManager()

    private var downloadRequest: DownloadRequest?
    private var isDownloading = false

    var listData: [MainModel] = []

    func doDownloding(onStarted: @escaping ()->()) {

       if listData.count == 0 || isDownloading {
            return
       }

        let firstModel = listData.first
        if checkMp3FileExists(model: firstModel!) {

            self.isDownloading = false
            self.listData.removeFirst()

            if self.listData.count > 0 {
                self.doDownloding {}
            }

            return

        }

        let mp3URLString = MyHelper.MEDIA_URL_PREFIX + (firstModel?.link)!
        let url = URL(string: mp3URLString)

        let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)

        //isDownloading = true
        onStarted()

        downloadRequest = Alamofire.download(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil, to: destination)
            .downloadProgress { (progress) in

            self.onDownloadProgress?(Float(progress.fractionCompleted))

            }.response { (response) in

                self.isDownloading = false
                self.onDownloadFinished?(true)

                if self.listData.count > 0 {
                    self.listData.removeFirst()
                }

                if self.listData.count > 0 {
                    self.doDownloding{}
                }

        }

    }

    func addSingleTask(mainModel: MainModel) {

        listData.append(mainModel)
        doDownloding{}

    }

    func addListTask(newList: [MainModel]) {

        listData.append(contentsOf: newList)
        doDownloding{}

    }

}
```

Comment: Avoid using singleton, or remove the property `onCompleted` and make it a parameter to `doDownload` method. Anyway, your `Service` class is wrongly designed and needs to be updated.

Comment: @OOPer i'm noob swift developer. can you write me `remove the property` and `without singleton`? thanks

Comment: Please  read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem. We don't need to see the implementation of `removeMp3FileIfExists` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of *remove the property `onCompleted` and make it a parameter to `doDownload` method*:

```
class Service {
     let static shared = Service()

     func doDownload(onCompleted: (()->())?) {
          //...
          onCompleted?()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**POINT 1**

You should be getting error in the below line

```
     let static shared = Service()
```

because static keyword should come first then declaration.

```
static let shared = Service()
```

**POINT 2**

Implement the onDownload function with Completion Handler

```
    func doDownload(onCompleted: @escaping ()->()) {
    onCompleted()
    }
```

Call the function as below

```
    let service = Service.shared
    service.doDownload { () in
        print("Called in completion Handler")
    }
```

for more detail about Closures go through the below link.
[Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

Comment: thank you for answer. `doDownload` is processing function and can not run it in two time.

Comment: i need run `doDownload` one time and get two callback of `onCompleted` in two views (context)

Comment: Then it will be better if you use delegate or notification

Comment: can i get one `protocol delegate` callback in multiple views?

Answer (score 1):

Your code in viewDidLoad looks good but could you re visit your singleton class and could you try running your code after adding a private init method calling super.init and see if your code works.

Comment: You have added a initializer in singleton correct . Can you remove let static shared from your singleton file and create a strong reference in your view controller and then call your completion block like                                  let service = Service(); then in viewDidLoad call service.onCompleted() and in collectionView cellForRow pass the service instance via a function argument. The reason closure does not gets called is we dont have a strong reference to it. Try this and let me know